# How to check if a single multi dimensional array contails same array as value in php?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, duplicates

I have an single multi-dimensional array, and want to compare its own value array's are duplicate or not.

Let the array is like :

```
$userdb = Array
(
    (0) => Array
        (
            'college' => 'college1',
            'name' => 'Anil Kumar',
            'city' => 'bikaner'
        ),

    (1) => Array
        (
            'college' => 'college2',
            'name' => 'Tanu Shree',
            'city' => 'bikaner'
        ),

    (2) => Array
        (
            'college' => 'college1',
            'name' => 'Anil Kumar',
            'city' => 'bikaner'
        )
);
```

Here two indexes are same, index 0 and 2.
How can I compare the whole sub-array of this multi-dimensional array for my single array $userdb.
I want to compare whole index's array not only fields.

Comment: [`array_diff_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php) ?

Comment: This comment might do your stuff. http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-diff.php#110572

Comment: I have single array.. :(

Comment: u just want to remove duplicate array?

Comment: No I want to prompt if there is any duplicate sub-arrays.

Comment: than chk the duplicate link

Comment: In that link there are 2 arrays not one.. :(

Comment: `$array != array_unique($array,SORT_REGULAR)` to check if there's duplicates in it.

Comment: `function checkCsvRowDuplicate($address)
{
    $addressCsv = $address;
    $array_new = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($addressCsv as $key => $addr) 
    {
        # code...
        foreach ($addr as $k => $value) 
        {
                $array_new[$i] .= $value.", " ;
        }
        $i++;
    }
     $duplicate = (array_count_values($array_new));
    $duplicate = array_values($duplicate);
   
    if(in_array('2',$duplicate))
    {
        return "duplicate";
    }
    else
    {
        return "unique";
    }   
    
}`